# Plot dynamic data in a chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I tried to plot a dynamic data in a chart with the code bellow, but i get the same data. because the last data crush the first one (one over the other ).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                            var unities = <%-JSON.stringify(unities) %>;
                            var data = <%-JSON.stringify(data) %>;

                            var dataTracer = {};
                            var arrayDate = [];
                            var arrayData = [];
                            var arrayDataTracer = [];
                            unities.forEach(function(docUnity){

                                data.forEach(function(docData) {
                                    if(docUnity.unity == "date"){
                                         arrayDate.push(docData[docUnity._id]);
                                    }});
                            });                            
                            unities.forEach(function(docUnity){
                                if(docUnity.unity != "date" && docUnity.type_cumul == "simple" && docUnity.archiver == 0) {

                                    dataTracer["x"] = arrayDate;
                                    dataTracer["name"] = docUnity.unity;
                                    dataTracer["type"] = 'scatter';

                                    data.forEach(function(docData) {
                                        arrayData.push(docData[docUnity._id]);
                                    });
                                    dataTracer["y"] = arrayData;
                                    alert(dataTracer);
                                    arrayDataTracer.push(dataTracer);
                                }
                            });

                            Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', arrayDataTracer);

                        </script>
```

**So the result is**

[image]

**And when i expect the results, I create more variables like this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                            var unities = <%-JSON.stringify(unities) %>;
                            var data = <%-JSON.stringify(data) %>;

                            var dataTracer = {};
                            var dataTracer2 = {};
                            var arrayDate = [];
                            var arrayData = [];
                            var arrayData2 = [];
                            var arrayDataTracer = [];
                            unities.forEach(function(docUnity){

                                data.forEach(function(docData) {
                                    if(docUnity.unity == "date"){
                                        arrayDate.push(docData[docUnity._id]);
                                    }});
                            });

                            unities.forEach(function(docUnity){

                                if(docUnity.unity == "Objectif"){
                                    dataTracer2["x"] = arrayDate;
                                    dataTracer2["name"] = docUnity.unity;
                                    dataTracer2["type"] = 'scatter';

                                    data.forEach(function(docData) {
                                            arrayData2.push(docData[docUnity._id]);
                                        });
                                    dataTracer2["y"] = arrayData2;
                                    alert(dataTracer2);
                                    arrayDataTracer.push(dataTracer2);
                                }
                            });
                            unities.forEach(function(docUnity){
                                if(docUnity.unity == "Resultat"){
                                    dataTracer["x"] = arrayDate;
                                    dataTracer["name"] = docUnity.unity;
                                    dataTracer["type"] = 'scatter';

                                    data.forEach(function(docData) {
                                        arrayData.push(docData[docUnity._id]);
                                    });
                                    dataTracer["y"] = arrayData;
                                    alert(dataTracer);
                                    arrayDataTracer.push(dataTracer);
                                }
                            });

                            Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', arrayDataTracer);

                        </script>
```

**And I get this** 
[image]

Comment: check IF Statement in first: if(docUnity.unity != "date" && docUnity.type_cumul == "simple" && docUnity.archiver == 0)        i dont see it in the second?

Comment: IF in first is for a global test, in the second i replace it just for the test. its okay with this statement.

Comment: show Structure of data Variable?

Comment: the structure should be like this [{ x : [], y : [], name : "###", type : "####"}, { x : [], y : [], name : "###", type : "####"},.....]

Comment: i resolve the problem, it should initiate the variables arrayData = [] and dataTracer = {}

Answer (score 0):

it should initiate the variables by adding those lines

```
arrayData = [];
dataTracer = {};
```

so the code will be

```
unities.forEach(function(docUnity){
                                if(docUnity.unity != "date" && docUnity.type_cumul == "simple" && docUnity.archiver == 0) {
                                //if(docUnity.unity == "Resultat"){
                                    dataTracer["x"] = arrayDate;
                                    data.forEach(function(docData) {
                                        arrayData.push(docData[docUnity._id]);
                                    });
                                    dataTracer["y"] = arrayData;
                                    arrayData = [];
                                    dataTracer["name"] = docUnity.unity;
                                    dataTracer["type"] = 'scatter';
                                    alert(dataTracer.y);
                                    arrayDataTracer.push(dataTracer);
                                    dataTracer = {};
                                }
                            });
```